# Photos not viewable in Mavericks iPhoto 9

Tags: macos

Some of my older photos appear as thumbnails ok in iPhoto after upgrading to OS X Mavericks, but on clicking on them I only get an exclamation mark in a triangle. The answers I found on Apple's discussion lists didn't apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the original photos were in Mac Classic 'pict' format - they must have come from scans of physical prints. Exported them from a laptop running  an earlier version of iPhoto, opened in Photoshop and saved as high quality jpegs. Then imported them into iPhoto 9 and discarded the originals. (You can change the date to the original if you wish so that iPhoto doesn't think 1994 is 2004).